# How to execute Git commands using cmd.exe being called from another application?

Tags: c#, command-line, process.start

I have an application that generates some files. Once the files are generated, i want to then perform some Git commands to start a local repository. I have spent a few days on multiple solutions and endless googling but i can't get this to work as expected.

If i manually kick off the .exe, locally or on a server, it works perfectly. However, when the application(MVC) calls the .exe it doesn't work locally or on a server. I will provide the code that calls the .exe itself and then what the .exe code is doing.

**MVC call to run .exe**

```
        //Call git exe 
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            Arguments = Arg1 + " " + Arg2,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            FileName = @"C:\Foo.exe"
        };

        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = processInfo
        };

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

This .exe gets launched without issue so this part is working i think. I checked it via task manager.

**Git command execution**

```
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                WorkingDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.OutPutDirectory
            },
        };

        process.Start();
        using (var writer = process.StandardInput)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("git init");
            writer.WriteLine("git add --all");
            writer.WriteLine("git commit --author=\"" + ParseUserNameFromEmail() + " <" + _userEmailAddress + ">\" -m \"Initial Commit\"");
        }
```

If i execute this part manually from the cmd prompt it works perfect on both local and server. But as soon as this .exe is called from an MVC app, it runs but the git repo isn't created as expected. I am at a total lost. I have tried running the process with my creds and a service account. I have also tried capturing the output in hope to shed light on what the issue could be but it's just empty on error and output redirects :(.

Comment: Why are you trying to run these commands _through_ cmd.exe instead of executing git.exe directly with the needed arguments?

Comment: Either option "should" work. I was just trying to stay close to the online solutions for executing cmd line from an application. Trying to reduce more variables to troubleshoot.